# Multiply an amount of numbers n-times in all variations

Tags: c

short version of my problem is:
I have an array with different numbers and I'd like to multiply them in all different variations n-times.
So for example the array could be

```
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
```

or it could also be like

```
int a[3] = { 3, 6, 9 }
```

next is I have a variable n that tells me how many times I want to multiply, so for example

```
int n = 2
# would lead to following results:
result = 3 * 3  # a[0] * a[0]
result = 3 * 6  # a[0] * a[1]
result = 3 * 9  # a[0] * a[2]
result = 6 * 6  # a[1] * a[1]
result = 6 * 9  # a[1] * a[2]
result = 9 * 9  # a[2] * a[2]

int n = 3
# would lead to following results:
result = 3 * 3 * 3 # a[0] * a[0] * a[0]
result = 3 * 3 * 6 # a[0] * a[0] * a[1]
result = 3 * 3 * 9 # a[0] * a[0] * a[2]
result = 3 * 6 * 6 # a[0] * a[1] * a[1]
result = 3 * 6 * 9 # a[0] * a[1] * a[2]
result = 3 * 9 * 9 # a[0] * a[2] * a[2]
result = 6 * 6 * 6 # a[1] * a[1] * a[1]
result = 6 * 6 * 9 # a[1] * a[1] * a[2]
result = 6 * 9 * 9 # a[1] * a[2] * a[2]
result = 9 * 9 * 9 # a[2] * a[2] * a[2]
```

For the bigger picture: I try to solve a riddle for the number 7.11
There are 4 floats that can be added or be multiplied and in both cases you end up with 7.11 
So I do some math in my code to get all the prime numbers I need to rebuild those 4 numbers. Then I have permutation on these 4 numbers and that will be my variable `n`. Next is to make three for-loops, one for every number but the last one, as this will be all the primes I have left. So I also need a way to skip certain values if I'm out of that prime number, but I guess that could work easily with a `continue` in a for-loop.

Comment: What is the "riddle for the number 7.11"? Is it an assignment from a book? Which book? What is the assignment or exercise?

Comment: As for your problem, remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. That means you could have a function taking `int *` as its argument, and you could pass an `int` array of *any* size to it. Then you of course needs to pass the size (number of elements) of the array as an argument, as well as the "window" size (`n` in your example). Start with that, and try to figure out the permutation algorithm on paper once you got the basis function working.